# Exception handling flow

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

Can you explain to me the sequence of exception handling when it has multiple blocks.
For example, I have an anonymous block that has two procedures, Proc_A and Proc_B. Proc_A is called and the exception is handled in Proc_A. What will happen next? Will it go back to the outer block exception or it will exit there?

Thanks

Comment: Go step by step to understand. Once the handle is given to the exception block, the caller is not aware of the error unless the handle is given back to the caller. You could **start** by reading http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear but here is my go at it:

Assume that you have the following code:

```
public void procA() throws Exception {
  procB();
}

public void procB() throws Exception {
  try {
    // code that throws an exception
  } catch (Exception exc) {
      // code to handle the exception
  }
}
```

Now if the catch block handles the exception it might go two ways.
1. You just handle the exception and the propagation of the exception stops. Normal proceding back to procA.
2. You decide to throw the exception further or throwing a new exception like this:

```
throw exc

throw new Exception();
```

In this case the exception will be propagated to procA. So it all depends on what you want.